# what is the difference between scene layers and render layers

Tags: render-layers, layers

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/post_process/layers.html

could someone please make a clearer explanation about the difference between the scene layers and the layer layers?

Comment: So you are looking for an explanation for Blender 2.79? Since blender 2.8 scene layers has been replaced with collections, maybe they are easier to undersand if you look at those. Can you explain what is not clear? The two pages on the manual seems quite detailed.

Comment: As Carlo says layers and render layers have been replaced by collections and view layers since 2.8, are you sure you want to learn the 2.79 system?

Comment: i hate the layout they made for the new versions. im very happy with 2.79. ill just experiment with render layers, scene layers and layer layers until i figure it out.